# MAgento new block

Tags: php, magento

Here is my structure:
in [template_name]/default/layout/page.xml I created new block:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" template="page/html/customblock.phtml" />
```

in  [template_name]/default/template/1column.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblock') ?>
```

and in [template_name]/default/template/page/html/customblock.phtml is

```
<h1 style="bacground-color:yellow">Hello this is new reference</h1>
```

exception log is empty, and my new block is not showing, enybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was helpfull for me:

```
 <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" as="customblock" translate="label">
      <label>featured block</label>
      <block type="page/html_topmenu" template="page/html/customblock.phtml"/>
  </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with 2 things your directory is not correct please change your directory 
put your template in page/switch
and call like in page.xml as below

```
 <block type="page/switch" name="customblock" as="customblock" template="page/switch/customblock.phtml"/>
```

and add your custom block to `default/template/page/switch/yourblock.phtml`

OR one another way is

If you're going to use template (phtml), your block should extend from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

So your block type should be `core/template`.

hope this will sure solve your problem

Comment: Tryed both, still nothing

Comment: will you please clear your cache ? and if you want to create your simple template try http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/creating-and-displaying-a-static-block-in-magento/

Comment: I have disabled cache